# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "какие"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Я посмотрю какие товары предлагаются по скидке в "Магните" на своем телефоне.

Нужна ли запятая перед "какие"?

Answer (score 1):

Я посмотрю, какие товары предлагаются по скидке в "Магните", на своем телефоне.

Смысл предложения в том, что человек смотрит на своем телефоне, какие товары предлагаются по скидке в "Магните" на своем телефоне.

Если же не поставить запятую после "Магните", то получится, что товары предлагаются на своем (товаров) телефоне.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это сложноподчинённое предложение. "Я посмотрю" - подлежащее и сказуемое; "товары предлагаются" - также подлежащее и сказуемое. "Какие" - союз, перед которым нужна запятая, чтобы отделить одно от другого.

Comment: Вы уверены, что одна запятая решит проблему?